# simple forms website on RoR- let the user go to a customized link which he can share that shows what he just inputted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, webforms, rubygems, formtastic

I'm a pretty big RoR novice but I've had a lot of problems with finding out even where to begin. 
I'm looking for any tutorials or examples of apps that lets a user fill out a simple form in ruby, takes that information, redirects to another page, and posts the information. The user would be able to share that unique link with others, which shows that information.

I've taken a look at various gems such as Formtastic and Simpleforms but the tutorials on Railscast are outdated and it's difficult to get working. I believe it's because I'm on Rails 3. 
I'm pretty lost here and if anything can just prod me in the general direction of where to start / give me general strategy of how I should tackle this, it'd be greatly appreciated. This seems incredibly easy but I'm making it harder for myself than what it is.

- I'm actually looking to take an intensive RoR course in a few weeks but I need to get this simple MVP app done (it'll include video by nimbb API) for a deadline... so while I should definitely be putting in the effort to learn rather than cheat and drift, your help this time around would really be great :)

Comment: Have a look at this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7283690/rails-ruby-tutorials-and-reference-materials

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To a large extent this functionally is baked into rails. The simplest way to do this is without any extra gems (besides the default ones):

In your terminal run:

```
rails g scaffold form name:string message:text
```

Then the user can go to example.com/forms/new and enter their info. Once they submit the form rails auto redirects them to the view page for that new data. The URL of that page which will be something like /forms/n where n is some integer is the link to share.

If your struggling with rails concepts I would look at the rails guides, especially: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

Comment: That's what I originally sensed as well, since I've done some initial tutorials. I think all the extra gem stuff is obscuring that. I'm guessing I'll be able to add some other fields, other than string, via forms and views. Thanks for this response- I'm going to play around with it now and I'll see how it goes.

Comment: Look up the documentation for `rails g scaffold` you can pass in a number of different field options and it will automatically create all the views and forms. (Also please remember to mark the question answered if you feel it was)